# highlight after page loaded jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This code is working fine if happen a click event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".last").click(function () {
    $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
   });
  });
```

Stackoverflow have a similar effect when click on section `StackExchange` and you can see the response an user has made.

**Is possible trigger `$(".last").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);` After the page is loaded? like stackoverflow effect?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".last").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

Or

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $(".last").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```